# C - Why the size_t is unrecognized in eclipse?

Tags: c, size-t

In eclipse it don't recognize the type **size_t**, it write error on it and a message **uknown type name 'size_t'**, 
it is written right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size_t` comes from `stddef.h` standard header file. You have to include it. You can also get it from `stdio.h` where it is also declared.